# Yii2: Kartik Gridview - exporting excel with a title above data cells

Tags: gridview, yii2

Is there any way to include a title in the kartid\grid\GridView when the grid is exported in Excel file format?

I am interested in exporting not only the data from the grid, but also the type of the grid. One means is to name the exported file accordingly but it wouldn't be the prefered way.
Adding some heading in a cell, above the actual data would do the job. However in the standard implementation of GridView such capability does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I just searching on the internet for the same solution, and discovered my own, by learning how kartik gridview export works, so here's the answer.

Kartik GridView Export, uses registered Module and Controller which you can find on `kartik\grid\controllers\ExportController`

The way it export is send the html table content using post to the export controller, then setup a response header correspond to export type you selected.

This way, you can modify your htm table content on the fly by adding row(tr) or column(td), as it directly posted when you click export.

Example Adding Header using jquery :

```
$("<tr><td colspan='7'>Your Header Title Here</td></tr>").prependTo('thead');
```

`colspan='7'` Assume your table has 7 column, so it will be merged center.

And if you want to hide the header, but not in the exported.

```
$("<tr style='visibility: collapse'><td colspan='7'>Your Header Title Here</td></tr>").prependTo('thead');
```